# Express parse queryParams with "+" sign

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express server and in my routes I have configured:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

In frontend I'm sending the request with Angular:

```
let params = new HttpParams().set('info', info);
if (email) {
  params = params.set('email', encodeURIComponent(email));
}

let res;

try {
  res = await this.http.get(`/api/users`, { headers: header, params }).toPromise();
  return res._embedded.users;
} catch (err) {
  return false;
}
```

I'm receiving from frontend a GET request with a query param `email=jhondoesd%2Btest%40trond.com` I expect to receive in my route handler `query:{email:"jhondoesd+test@trond.com"}` but instead I'm receiving `query:{email:"jhondoesd%2Btest%40trond.com"}` so it seems that the query params aren't being decoded. What do I need to configure?

Comment: I just tried running these directly through the `querystring` and `qs` parsers (which express uses. `extended: false` uses `querystring`, otherwise `qs`) and it seems to work fine for both: `{ email: 'jhondoesd+test@trond.com' }` - are you sure the `app.use` is being called in the right place?

Comment: Please show how you make the query in the frontend - is whatever you're making the request with encoding the query string for you? That would explain the double encoding. Also, isn't `express.urlencoded` only related to parsing the *body*? Not the query?

Comment: @cbr I'm using `encodeURIComponent(email)` to encode the data before sending the GET request.

Comment: @omnidan `app.use` is before the routes handler so it should be called before. I just checked and if the GET is made like `/api/users/jhondoesd%2Btest%40trond.com` y receive `/api/users/jhondoesd+test@trond.com` so as @cbr says the parsing does work for the body but not for the query. Do you have any configuration to make it work also on query params?

Comment: if you're using it like that, you're using it in the path and you're looking for `encodeURI`. You use `encodeURIComponent` if you're working with query strings, e.g. ?foo=bar

Comment: @cbr Yes, I'm using query params. I updated the question above with the code of the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question so maybe someone else find this useful. As @cbr said this is an open issue with angular. I tried the solution given in [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18261#issuecomment-426383787) post and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are URI encoding the email while sending the parameter.

Try removing `encodeURIComponent(email)` from your email parameter. So;

`params = params.set('email', email);`

should do the trick.

Comment: I tried this, it works with the "@" but replaces the "+" with a space so the result is `{email:"jhondoesd test@trond.com"}`

Comment: @alexortizl that appears to be an open issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18261